# make image 100% height but proportional width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem and I think I am just having trouble wording the question which is why I can't find an answer.

I have a site that has an image that spans 100% height on a column. When you're looking at it above a viewport width of 1000px it looks awesome. But as you scroll down it obviously distorts and is super stretched, like the image here:

[image]

My question is, how can I have an image that is not a background image, that stretches 100% height, but maintains aspect ratio. Kind of like the supersized js plugin, but only on a single div instead of the whole background.

a live version of the site can be seen at http://faithpointdallas.com/422studios

it works as desired in firefox and totally sucks in safari. Any way to accomplish the firefox result in all browsers?

Thanks ahead of time for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a background-image? There's the `background-size` property that does exactly what you want.

Remove the `topImage` div in your HTML and try this:

```
div.top {
  background: url("../img/dallas.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover transparent;
  min-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I've done this but like I was afraid of, it doesn't work in safari or in IE 8. I don't care about IE 7, but it must work for 8 as well. So theres no way of doing this cross browser compatible? You can see the edits on the site.

Comment: Ok I got it to work, just for future people looking at this, I had to add "respond.js" to my js includes so everything worked in IE7+. I also had to add background-size:cover; on a seperate line rather than shorthand in the background style. Everythings working now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use CSS to mention the width as 100%. It should solve your problem.

```
background-size: 100%;
```

for more do check here http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/